# Can I carry a non-mercury thermometer on plane?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage

So I found this multi-tool thing in my drawer, recently, which has:

- A magnifying glass, allowed on-board, I think.
- A compass, also OK.
- and a thermometer, not OK.

However, the thermometer is covered in plastic very tightly and the liquid is red (mercury isn't red, is it?), so would that be OK on a plane? I don't need it, I am just curious if it is allowed and if there is anything I can do...

Comment: Well, not really, as I did explain that the liquid is wrapped in plastic, and is built into the tool, and the liquid might not be mercury...

Comment: Explaining that to the TSA won't go well, I suspect. Thermometers are not allowed, trying to justify a different material / liquid build won't work - they're not expected to be scientists and know about liquids, just to ban thermometers.

Comment: Are themometers banned by TSA? I can't find any reference to such a ban on [their site](https://search.usa.gov/search?query=thermometer&op=Search&affiliate=tsa.gov). I've had a [mini thermometer](http://www.amazon.com/Compass-Thermometer-Zipper-Backpack-Keychain/dp/B003XLXX3Y) on my jacket for years and have never been questioned about it by TSA. The FAA specifically [allows](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/media/materialscarriedbypassengersandcrew.pdf) a "Small personal mercury
thermometer in a protective
case"

Comment: @Johnny actually it is allowed, use the "Can I bring My...?" tool in [this page](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items)...

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate since this question is not about mercury thermometers. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the liquid is red, it's mostly likely alcohol (ethanol), not mercury (so less of an issue- even if it broke it would be no worse than spilling a few drops of wine). Even small mercury thermometers are [specifically allowed](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/media/materialscarriedbypassengersandcrew.pdf), as Johnny says:

[image]

By the TSA and some other authorities (but Cathay Pacific, for example, does not allow them).

So I think it should be okay, but you never know- you might lose it if some overzealous agent deems it a danger.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I didn't take it just in case but I will next time.